# Ionic - Error: Cannot find module 'jshint' while building a release.apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am new in this. I am developing an app in ionic framework. and now i want to create a build of release.apk.  and i am referring following tutorial to build release.apk -

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-toturial-for-building-a-release-apk/15758

but in this tutorial on #7 when i run `ionic build android --release` command then i am facing following error -

```
module.js:338
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'jshint'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
        at require (module.js:384:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/directory/appname/hooks/before_prepare/01_jshint.js:5:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    Error: Hook failed with error code 1: /directory/appname/hooks/before_prepare/01_jshint.js
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:194:23
        at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
        at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
        at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Question - How could i resolve this error? anyone please suggest me what's wrong with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the installed hook located at `PROJECT_ROOT/hooks/before_prepare/01_jshint.js` requires the node module `jshint`. You can install it using NPM:

```
npm install jshint
```

You can also save this dependency to your `package.json`:

```
npm install jshint --save
```

If you set up the project on another computer or a different directory you could just type `npm install` to install all the project's dependencies.

If you run into more errors after this one, look at the error thrown and search for the text `Cannot find module 'jshint'`. Where the text `jshint` will be something different. Perhaps more NPM modules are missing. Install these on the same way you did for `jshint`.

Also note that JSHint will exit the build process once it finds any errors in your Javascript files. [Scroll true all output to find the error reporting](http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/cordova-hooks-deep-drive-into-my-js-hint-hook-written-in-nodejs).

Comment: Ok. Thanks . that problem resolved but after that i am facing following error : Error: Hook failed with error code 1: /directory/appname/hooks/before_prepare/01_jshint.js

Comment: Not sure what you are asking now? If you need more information, please update your question

Comment: when i run command ionic build android --release ,
getting error : Hook failed with error code 1

Comment: Also note that JSHint will exit the build process once it finds any errors in your Javascript files. Scroll true all output to find the error reporting.

Comment: Read this: http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/cordova-hooks-deep-drive-into-my-js-hint-hook-written-in-nodejs

Comment: Please in which directory I could install the jshint